# can't connect to studio 3t "connection failed"

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I'm trying to create a new mongo database in studio 3t but after creating the database when I try to connect to it connection fails and I get this error.

```
Connection failed.

SERVER [localhost:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketOpenException): Exception opening socket
|____/ Socket error: Connection refused: no further information

Details:
Timed out after 5000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information}}]
```

Comment: Did you start the MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem connection Studio 3T with MongoDB earlier this week, and it consumed my entire working day, so I gave up on using Studio 3T to ensure time for other things and an alternative.  Today I found this short video tutorial by Studio 3T on how to connect Studio 3T with MongoDB.  Following the directions, I was surprised that a connection was made successfully.

For your solution, I recommend that you watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Ka3-HGNlYE

If this answer helps you, remember to tick to highlight it for others.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are not running `mongod.exe`.

First, run as adminastor and then connect to db:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxxJMbJq1U8

follow this youtube video